# slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds using Java API

Tags: java, tensorflow

I have generated a SavedModel which I can use with the following Python code

```
import base64
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
​
​
fn_load_image = lambda filename: np.array([base64.urlsafe_b64encode(open(filename, "rb").read())])
filename='test.jpg'
with tf.Session() as sess:
    loaded = tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ['serve'], 'tools/base64_model/1')
    image = fn_load_image(filename)
    p = sess.run('predictions:0', feed_dict={"input:0": image})
    print(p)
```

This gives me the values I expect.

When using the Java code below on the same model

```
    // load the model Bundle
    try (SavedModelBundle b = SavedModelBundle.load("tools/base64_model/1",
            "serve")) {

        // create the session from the Bundle
        Session sess = b.session();

        // base64 representation of JPG
        byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(new File((args[0]))));

        String encodedString = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(content);

        Tensor t = Tensors.create(encodedString);

        // run the model and get the classification
        final List<Tensor<?>> result = sess.runner().feed("input", 0, t).fetch("predictions", 0).run();

        // print out the result.
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

which should be equivalent i.e I send the base64 representation of an image to a model, I am getting an exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: slice
>   index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds.      [[{{node map/strided_slice}}]]
>     at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Native Method)    at
>   org.tensorflow.Session.access$100(Session.java:48)    at
>   org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.runHelper(Session.java:326)     at
>   org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.run(Session.java:276)   at
>   com.stolencamerafinder.storm.crawler.bolt.enrichments.HelloTensorFlow.main(HelloTensorFlow.java:35)

Should the Tensor have different content? Here is what **saved_model_cli** is telling me about my model.

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: input:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['outputs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: predictions:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You model is expecting an input tensor of rank-1 while you provide a tensor of rank-0.

This line produces a scalar tensor of a variable length (i.e. a `DT_STRING`).

```java
Tensor t = Tensors.create(encodedString);
```

However, the expected tensor is of rank-1, as you can see by the shape `(-1)` here, meaning that it expects a vector of a various number of elements.

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: input:0
```

So probably your issue will be fixed by passing an array of strings. This is possible using the `Tensors` factories only if you keep you pass your string as an array of array of bytes, like this:

```java
// base64 representation of JPG
byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(new File((args[0]))));
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encode(content);
Tensor t = Tensors.create(new byte[][]{ encodedBytes });
...
```

Comment: Would you know how to do this in TF 2.3 (Java 0.3.1)?

Comment: I created a separate question for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68211406/why-do-i-get-slice-index-0-of-dimension-0-out-of-bounds-error-in-tensorflow-fo