# Why do I get "slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds" error in Tensorflow for Java?

Tags: java, tensorflow

I have a model with the following signature that I'm trying to invoke using [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) for Java:

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:
signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['jpegbase64_bytes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['predictions'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 256)
        name: model/global_average_pooling2d/Mean:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

My code to invoke the model looks like this:

```
float[] predict(byte[] imageBytes) {
    try (Tensor result = SavedModelBundle.load("model.pb", "serve").session().runner()
            .feed("myinput", 0, TString.tensorOfBytes(NdArrays.scalarOfObject(imageBytes)))
            .fetch("myoutput")
            .run()
            .get(0)) {
        float[] buffer = new float[256];
        FloatNdArray floatNdArray = FloatDenseNdArray.create(RawDataBufferFactory.create(buffer, false),
                Shape.of(1, description.getNumFeatures()));
        ((TFloat32) result).copyTo(floatNdArray);
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

However, this throws the following errors:

```
slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
     [[{{node map/TensorArrayUnstack/strided_slice}}]]
org.tensorflow.exceptions.TFInvalidArgumentException: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
     [[{{node map/TensorArrayUnstack/strided_slice}}]]
    at org.tensorflow.internal.c_api.AbstractTF_Status.throwExceptionIfNotOK(AbstractTF_Status.java:87)
    at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Session.java:691)
    at org.tensorflow.Session.access$100(Session.java:72)
    at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.runHelper(Session.java:381)
    at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.run(Session.java:329)
    at com.mridang.myapp.ImageModel.predict(ImageModel.java:69)
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

From what I've understood, the model requires a dense-type string tensor while mine isn't. I found this answer on Stackoverflow [slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds using Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61389869/slice-index-0-of-dimension-0-out-of-bounds-using-java-api) but that seems to relate to very old version of [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow).

I'm using these dependencies:

```
layer group: 'org.tensorflow', name: 'tensorflow-core-platform', version: '0.3.1'
layer group: 'org.tensorflow', name: 'tensorflow-framework', version: '0.3.1'
```

Comment: I am not familiar with TF with Java, only with Python, but reviewing the linked question you provided, probably the reason of your problem is that your are providing a `rank-0` whereas TF expects a `rank-1` tensor instead. Have you tried this? `feed("myinput", 0, TString.tensorOfBytes(NdArrays.vectorOf(imageBytes)))`. Please, note the change from `scalarOfObject` to `vectorOf` when constructing your tensor with `NdArrays`. Please, see the relevant [javadocs](https://www.tensorflow.org/jvm/api_docs/java/org/tensorflow/ndarray/NdArrays#vectorOf(byte...))

Comment: @jccampanero I think we're on the same page, however, it doesn't seem to be possible to use the snippet you provided.
`vectorOf` returns an `NdArray<Byte>` while the `TString.tensorOfBytes` requires a `NdArray<byte[]>`. The docs don't outline any scenarions so I'm very lost as to how to invoke the method. Most methods are private or protected as well. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @jccampanero answer. A bit of digging and I found a reference in the Zoltar library that showed how to do this.

https://github.com/spotify/zoltar/blob/b2c4c86f06c043aae505c533467e8a42d12da2d8/zoltar-tensorflow/src/main/java/com/spotify/zoltar/tf/TensorFlowPredictFn.java#L69

I need to create a vector of objects apparently and the following snippet did the trick.

```
float[] predict(byte[] imageBytes) {
    try (Tensor result = SavedModelBundle.load("model.pb", "serve").session().runner()
            .feed("myinput", 0, TString.tensorOfBytes(NdArrays.vectorOfObjects(imageBytes)))
            .fetch("myoutput")
            .run()
            .get(0)) {
        float[] buffer = new float[description.getNumFeatures()];
        FloatNdArray floatNdArray = FloatDenseNdArray.create(RawDataBufferFactory.create(buffer, false),
                Shape.of(1, description.getNumFeatures()));
        ((TFloat32) result).copyTo(floatNdArray);
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great Mridang, I'm very happy to see that you were able to solve the problem. I am very sorry that I was not of more help in the final resolution of the problem.

Comment: Thx again for the nudge in the right direction. The docs around TF for Java seem to be extremely sparse.

Comment: You are welcome Mridang;) I agree with you: in my opinion there is great stuff but it can be improved in several things like the docs or with some examples, for instance.

Comment: Happy you found the answer! For simplification though, you can easily copy your resulting tensor to a `float[]` array doing this: `StdArrays.copyFrom((TFloat32)result, buffer);`